# Webpack babel config for both server and client javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to figure out how to have a single webpack config file that works for transforming both server (node.js) js and client js with the es2015 preset. Currently I have to specifically set "target: 'node'" for it to correctly process node-based files. If I don't, then webpack does the transformation based on the default "target: 'web'". It then reports errors because the 'mysql' module being imported clearly won't work for web.

How can I unify both into the same config file so that server and client js will be transformed separately? Or do I need separate configs entirely?

Sample webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './index.js',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'       
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Sample js code

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import mysql from 'mysql';

class Test {
  constructor () {

  }

  get read () {

  }
};
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can pass multiple configs for Webpack to process at the same time. Simply return an array of configuration objects.

```
export default [
  { 
    // config 1 here
  },
  {
    // config 2 here
  },
];
```

Extra tip: if you use `.babel.js` as extension for your config file, Webpack will run it through Babel for you, which allows you to use ES6 in your Webpack config.

Bonus: the snippet below

```js
// Source: https://gist.github.com/Ambroos/f23d517a4261e52b4591224b4c8df826

import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

import CleanPlugin from 'clean-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import AssetsPlugin from 'assets-webpack-plugin';
import CompressionPlugin from 'compression-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import rucksack from 'rucksack-css';
import cssnano from 'cssnano';
import moment from 'moment';

const sharedPlugins = [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /nl/),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin({}),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            screw_ie8: true,
            sequences: true,
            properties: true,
            dead_code: true,
            drop_debugger: true,
            conditionals: true,
            comparisons: true,
            evaluate: true,
            booleans: true,
            loops: true,
            unused: true,
            if_return: true,
            join_vars: true,
            cascade: true,
            negate_iife: true,
            hoist_funs: true,
            warnings: false,
        },
        mangle: {
            screw_ie8: true,
        },
        output: {
            screw_ie8: true,
            preamble: '/* Website - ' + moment().format() + ' */',
        },
    }),
];

const sharedServerPlugins = [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /nl/),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin({}),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            drop_console: false,
            screw_ie8: true,
            sequences: true,
            properties: true,
            dead_code: true,
            drop_debugger: false,
            conditionals: true,
            comparisons: true,
            evaluate: true,
            booleans: true,
            loops: true,
            unused: true,
            if_return: true,
            join_vars: true,
            cascade: true,
            negate_iife: true,
            hoist_funs: true,
            warnings: false,
        },
        mangle: {
            screw_ie8: true,
        },
        output: {
            screw_ie8: true,
            preamble: '/* Website - ' + moment().format() + ' */',
        },
    }),
];

const PATHS = {
    build: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    sourcemaps: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'sourcemaps'),
    browserSource: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'browser', 'index.js'),
    browserBuild: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'browser'),
    serverSource: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'server', 'index.js'),
    serverAssetsSource: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'server', 'assets', 'index.js'),
    serverBuild: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'server'),
};

export default [
    // Browser
    {
        entry: { browser: PATHS.browserSource },
        output: {
            path: PATHS.browserBuild,
            filename: 's/[chunkhash].js',
            chunkFilename: 's/async-[chunkhash].js',
            publicPath: '/',
            sourceMapFilename: '../sourcemaps/browser/[file].map',
        },
        devtool: 'hidden-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new AssetsPlugin({
                prettyPrint: true,
                path: path.resolve(PATHS.build, 'browserAssets'),
                filename: 'index.js',
                processOutput: assets => `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(assets, null, '    ')};`,
            }),
            new CleanPlugin([PATHS.browserBuild, PATHS.sourcemaps], path.resolve(PATHS.build, 'browserAssets')),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('s/[contenthash].css'),
            new CompressionPlugin({
                asset: '{file}.gz',
                algorithm: 'gzip',
                regExp: /\.js$|\.html$|\.css$|\.svg$|\.eot$|\.xml$/,
                threshold: 1400,
                minRation: 0.8,
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                    WEBPACK_ENV: JSON.stringify('browser'),
                    APP_ENV: (process.env.APP_ENV && JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENV)) || undefined,
                },
            }),
        ].concat(sharedPlugins),
        externals: [
            { browserConfig: 'var websiteBrowserConfig' },
            { programs: 'var programs' },
        ],
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                        'style',
                        [
                            'css?importLoaders=2&localIdentName=css-module-[hash:base64]',
                            'postcss',
                            'sass',
                        ]
                    ),
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|ico)$/i,
                    loaders: [
                        'url?limit=1400&name=s/i/[sha512:hash:base64:16].[ext]',
                        'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug',
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /isotope\-|fizzy\-ui\-utils|desandro\-|masonry|outlayer|get\-size|doc\-ready|eventie|eventemitter/,
                    loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window',
                },
                {
                    test: /flickity/,
                    loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window',
                },
                {
                    test: /node_modules\/unipointer/,
                    loader: 'imports?define=>undefined',
                },
            ],
        },
        postcss: () => {
            return [rucksack, autoprefixer, cssnano];
        },
    },

    // Server assets
    {
        entry: { assets: PATHS.serverAssetsSource },
        target: 'node',
        output: {
            path: PATHS.browserBuild,
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            filename: '../serverAssets/index.js',
            publicPath: '/',
        },
        plugins: [
            // assetsWriter,
            new CompressionPlugin({
                asset: '{file}.gz',
                algorithm: 'gzip',
                regExp: /\.js$|\.html$|\.css$|\.svg$|\.eot$|\.xml$/,
                threshold: 1400,
                minRation: 0.8,
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                    WEBPACK_ENV: JSON.stringify('assets'),
                    APP_ENV: (process.env.APP_ENV && JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENV)) || undefined,
                },
            }),
        ].concat(sharedPlugins),
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|ico)$/i,
                    loaders: [
                        'url?limit=1400&name=s/i/[sha512:hash:base64:16].[ext]',
                        'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug',
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    },

    // Server
    {
        entry: PATHS.serverSource,
        target: 'node',
        output: {
            path: PATHS.build,
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            filename: 'server/server.js',
            publicPath: '/s/',
            sourceMapFilename: 'sourcemaps/browser/[file].map',
        },
        externals: [
            { serverAssets: '../serverAssets/index.js' },
            { browserAssets: '../browserAssets/index.js' },
            { vrtConfig: '../../env_vars.js' },
            /^(?!\.|\/).+/i,
            /webpack-assets\.json/,
        ],
        plugins: [
            new CleanPlugin(PATHS.serverBuild),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                    WEBPACK_ENV: JSON.stringify('server'),
                    APP_ENV: (process.env.APP_ENV && JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENV)) || undefined,
                },
            }),
        ].concat(sharedServerPlugins),
        node: {
            __dirname: false,
            __filename: false,
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json',
                },
            ],
        },
    },
];
```

That is the config we use in one of our sites with a partially shared codebase, and partially shared assets. It consists of three Webpack builds in one:

- Browser
- Server assets (images/fonts/... that will be referenced in server-generated HTML)
- Server code (Node)

The server code has a few special properties:

- `target: 'node'` (Webpack needs this)
- `output.libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` (makes Webpack use commonjs for unbundled libs)
- `externals: [ /^(?!\.|\/).+/i, ]` (makes Webpack not bundle anything in node_modules, or anything that is not a relative path (starting with `.` or `/`)

This combination makes Webpack only process your own code, and access other  modules and libraries through require. Which means your dependencies using native bindings won't break as they won't be bundled.

Comment: thanks again! I ran into another problem where node_modules was being included and after a few hours ended up back at your original answer. After reading more closely and adding both the libraryTarget and externals code, things are working awesome. Thanks dude!

Comment: Any idea if there's a way to order the compilation? e.g. don't run the server config until the client has finished. I've got a scenario where I generate a manifest from the client and want to bundle it into the server. Apart from possibly doing something clever with the compiler hooks, or creating separate config files (yuck), I've sort of conceded to loading the file at runtime instead of bundling.

Comment: @James I have the same question

Comment: @James and @K.King, you can achieve this by adding a name property to your config for each variant (name: 'client' for example), and then in your package.json create a build step that builds your environments sequentially with `webpack --config-name client && webpack --config-name server`.