# Webpack target=node and babel

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

How do I start a webpack project with node express.
I tried webtack target-node attribute but the file I was targeting was't processed by babel as expected. webpack config file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
var fs = require('fs');


var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
  __DEV__: true
};

export default  {
  name:'server',
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: false, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: './tools/socketServer.js',
  target: 'node', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`, // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/', // Use absolute paths to avoid the way that URLs are resolved by Chrome when they're parsed from a dynamically loaded CSS blob. Note: Only necessary in Dev.
    filename: '/bundle.js'
  },
  externals: nodeModules,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS), // Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.htmlnew webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']}
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here, it includes a bunch of stuff to make node-side Webpack+Babel work and has an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369053/webpack-babel-config-for-both-server-and-client-javascript/37391247#37391247

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you copied your code from [here](https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I#p28). I think your issue lies in the fact that you're using `export default` instead of `module.exports`. Node < v13 doesn't support `import/export` so that's likely the crux of your issue.