# os.hostname() is empty after transpiling through babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So, I'm writing a server side app in ES6/node. Below is the offending code. I know that's not ES6, but other parts of the app are (and ideally, I'd be using ES6's import - I only fell back to require because I wanted to test the raw code in node itself without the need for transpiling.

```
var os = require("os");
var hostname = os.hostname();
console.log(hostname);
```

So, if I have a JavaScript file called, say, test.js, with that code in it... Then I throw that at node I get the correct hostname printed on the console.

But if I run it through babel, when I run it, I get nothing. No output at all.

Interestingly enough, if I add this line to the code:

console.log(os)

then the raw JS gives me this output:

```
{ hostname: [Function: getHostname],
  uptime: [Function: getUptime],
  freemem: [Function: getFreeMem],
  totalmem: [Function: getTotalMem],
  cpus: [Function: getCPUs],
  type: [Function: getOSType],
  release: [Function: getOSRelease],
  networkInterfaces: [Function: getInterfaceAddresses],
  homedir: [Function: getHomeDirectory],
  userInfo: [Function: getUserInfo],
  loadavg: [Function: loadavg],
  constants:
   { UV_UDP_REUSEADDR: 4,
     errno:
      { E2BIG: 7,
        EACCES: 13,
        EADDRINUSE: 98,
        EADDRNOTAVAIL: 99,
        EAFNOSUPPORT: 97,
        EAGAIN: 11,
        EALREADY: 114,
        EBADF: 9,
        EBADMSG: 74,
        EBUSY: 16,
        ECANCELED: 125,
        ECHILD: 10,
        ECONNABORTED: 103,
        ECONNREFUSED: 111,
        ECONNRESET: 104,
        EDEADLK: 35,
        EDESTADDRREQ: 89,
        EDOM: 33,
        EDQUOT: 122,
        EEXIST: 17,
        EFAULT: 14,
        EFBIG: 27,
        EHOSTUNREACH: 113,
        EIDRM: 43,
        EILSEQ: 84,
        EINPROGRESS: 115,
        EINTR: 4,
        EINVAL: 22,
        EIO: 5,
        EISCONN: 106,
        EISDIR: 21,
        ELOOP: 40,
        EMFILE: 24,
        EMLINK: 31,
        EMSGSIZE: 90,
        EMULTIHOP: 72,
        ENAMETOOLONG: 36,
        ENETDOWN: 100,
        ENETRESET: 102,
        ENETUNREACH: 101,
        ENFILE: 23,
        ENOBUFS: 105,
        ENODATA: 61,
        ENODEV: 19,
        ENOENT: 2,
        ENOEXEC: 8,
        ENOLCK: 37,
        ENOLINK: 67,
        ENOMEM: 12,
        ENOMSG: 42,
        ENOPROTOOPT: 92,
        ENOSPC: 28,
        ENOSR: 63,
        ENOSTR: 60,
        ENOSYS: 38,
        ENOTCONN: 107,
        ENOTDIR: 20,
        ENOTEMPTY: 39,
        ENOTSOCK: 88,
        ENOTSUP: 95,
        ENOTTY: 25,
        ENXIO: 6,
        EOPNOTSUPP: 95,
        EOVERFLOW: 75,
        EPERM: 1,
        EPIPE: 32,
        EPROTO: 71,
        EPROTONOSUPPORT: 93,
        EPROTOTYPE: 91,
        ERANGE: 34,
        EROFS: 30,
        ESPIPE: 29,
        ESRCH: 3,
        ESTALE: 116,
        ETIME: 62,
        ETIMEDOUT: 110,
        ETXTBSY: 26,
        EWOULDBLOCK: 11,
        EXDEV: 18 },
     signals:
      { SIGHUP: 1,
        SIGINT: 2,
        SIGQUIT: 3,
        SIGILL: 4,
        SIGTRAP: 5,
        SIGABRT: 6,
        SIGIOT: 6,
        SIGBUS: 7,
        SIGFPE: 8,
        SIGKILL: 9,
        SIGUSR1: 10,
        SIGSEGV: 11,
        SIGUSR2: 12,
        SIGPIPE: 13,
        SIGALRM: 14,
        SIGTERM: 15,
        SIGCHLD: 17,
        SIGSTKFLT: 16,
        SIGCONT: 18,
        SIGSTOP: 19,
        SIGTSTP: 20,
        SIGTTIN: 21,
        SIGTTOU: 22,
        SIGURG: 23,
        SIGXCPU: 24,
        SIGXFSZ: 25,
        SIGVTALRM: 26,
        SIGPROF: 27,
        SIGWINCH: 28,
        SIGIO: 29,
        SIGPOLL: 29,
        SIGPWR: 30,
        SIGSYS: 31,
        SIGUNUSED: 31 } },
  arch: [Function],
  platform: [Function],
  tmpdir: [Function],
  tmpDir: [Function],
  getNetworkInterfaces: [Function: deprecated],
  EOL: '\n',
  endianness: [Function] }
```

And the transpiled code gives me this output

```
{ endianness: [Function],
  hostname: [Function],
  loadavg: [Function],
  uptime: [Function],
  freemem: [Function],
  totalmem: [Function],
  cpus: [Function],
  type: [Function],
  release: [Function],
  getNetworkInterfaces: [Function],
  networkInterfaces: [Function],
  arch: [Function],
  platform: [Function],
  tmpDir: [Function],
  tmpdir: [Function],
  EOL: '\n' }
```

I downloaded the and installed the babel plugin "[transform-inline-environment-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables)" and my .babelrc contains the line

```
"plugins": ["transform-inline-environment-variables"]
```

But that doesn't seem to have done anything. What am I doing wrong? This app needs to know what host it's running on - It may run on different hosts, and will need to do different things based on the name of the host.

Any help gratefully received. This is my first foray into server side JavaScript.

As requested, the transpiled code:

```
!function(n){function t(e){if(r[e])return r[e].exports;var o=r[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return n[e].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,t),o.l=!0,o.exports}var r={};t.m=n,t.c=r,t.i=function(n){return n},t.d=function(n,r,e){t.o(n,r)||Object.defineProperty(n,r,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:e})},t.n=function(n){var r=n&&n.__esModule?function(){return n.default}:function(){return n};return t.d(r,"a",r),r},t.o=function(n,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,t)},t.p="",t(t.s=1)}([function(n,t,r){"use strict";t.endianness=function(){return"LE"},t.hostname=function(){return"undefined"!=typeof location?location.hostname:""},t.loadavg=function(){return[]},t.uptime=function(){return 0},t.freemem=function(){return Number.MAX_VALUE},t.totalmem=function(){return Number.MAX_VALUE},t.cpus=function(){return[]},t.type=function(){return"Browser"},t.release=function(){return"undefined"!=typeof navigator?navigator.appVersion:""},t.networkInterfaces=t.getNetworkInterfaces=function(){return{}},t.arch=function(){return"javascript"},t.platform=function(){return"browser"},t.tmpdir=t.tmpDir=function(){return"/tmp"},t.EOL="\n"},function(n,t,r){"use strict";var e=r(0),o=e.hostname();console.log(e),console.log(o)}]);
```

That all looks very scary to me. I've been writing JavaScript since it was LiveScript in 1995 and babel's output has always completely baffled me, LOL.

Comment: `But if I run it through babel, when I run it, I get nothing. No output at all.` what does the transpiled code look like?

Comment: Added to the question. Sorry for the omission!

Comment: Hehe. Sorry. Cut and paste delay there :)

Comment: wonder why it's doing `t.hostname = function() {
        return "undefined" != typeof location ? location.hostname : ""
    }` - clearly, `location` is undefined - that looks like it's more than being transpiled! It's almost as if it's taking code that would run in nodejs and converting to code that would run in a browser, perhaps? (pasting that line into browser console confirms my suspicion)

Comment: Oh, yeah. I wonder if there's a babel configuration setting that will fix that

Comment: Personally, I've never know babel to do that

Comment: That totally worked. Thank you! Turned out it was webpack, not babel doing it... I probably should have mentioned that. I didn't realize it was important. The answer, technically, was to add target: 'node' to my webpack config. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as valid. I'd love for you to get the points because you put me on the right path. Otherwise, I'll add it myself, just so others can get to it.

Comment: `I probably should have mentioned that` I was about to ask if you're using webpack or similar :p

Comment: Please, add the answer yourself, I may have "put you on the path", but you found the answer yourself :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was the webpack config that was causing the problem. Jaromanda X noticed that the transpiled code was targetting the browser instead of node, and a quick google search brought up this SO question: [Webpack babel config for both server and client javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369053/webpack-babel-config-for-both-server-and-client-javascript/37391247)

So the solution (in the answer to that question) is simply to add a line to the webpack config:

```
target: 'node'
```