# Separate client and server in Webpack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webpack

Goal. Configuring app, which has: React, Webpack and MongoDB.

So, I've already setup Webpack for React and tried import Mongoose. The problem: React client-side and Mongoose - server-side, and because of that Webpack must have configurations for both. Using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37391247/7479176 I tried to configure Webpack. After that, I tried import Mongoose in my server.jsx file, but it didn't work.

Question. How to configure Webpack, so I can work with MongoDB?

**Edited**. I figured out how to rid of warnings (see Warnings):

```
output: {
            filename: 'bundle.node.js',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        externals: [
            /^(?!\.|\/).+/i
        ],
```

But, when I added code into server.jsx (see server.jsx), it didn't log message in console.

Webpack configurations:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = [
    {
        entry: {
            index: './src/app/app.jsx'
        },
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            port: 3000,
            host: 'localhost',
            historyApiFallback: true,
            noInfo: false,
            stats: 'minimal',
            hot: true, // Tell the dev-server we're using HMR
            contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            publicPath: '/'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // Enable HMR
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/index.html',
                filename: 'index.html',
                inject: 'body'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                },
                {
                   test: /\.css$/,
                   use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] 
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        entry: {
            index: './src/server/server.jsx'
        },
        target: 'node',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.node.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: ['babel-loader']
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

server.jsx:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import '../config/database.js'

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect(config.database)
// check connection
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
// check for db errors
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => console.log(err))
```

Warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
10:13-49 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
82:18-42 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
90:20-44 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
97:35-67 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vertx' in 'D:\Projects\JavaScriptProjects\pizzaday\node_modules\es6-promise\dist'
 @ ./node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js 131:20-30
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
 @ ./src/server/server.jsx
```

Comment: IMHO Client and Server really should be in separate projects, or at the very least within separate folder hierarchies if you insist on putting both in the same root project folder. Personally I always keep the backend separate, and merely pass in proxy options for the webpack dev server to "pass through" to the separately running server during development. And in real life, front and back quite often have decoupled deployment cycles. So there is that to consider as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. I used webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware with basic Express server. I tried launch MongoDB with React on webpack-dev-server and thats was main problem.

I made new server.js within separate folder following advice from Neil Lunn and setup basic Express server with middleware and split Webpack config into 3 separate files common, dev and prod.

This fragment of code in server.js helped me to run server and client together with Webpack which bonded everything together:

```
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}))

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))
```

New Webpack config (webpack.common.js):

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=2000&reload=true',
            './src/index.jsx'
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
               test: /\.css$/,
               use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```